# Hide credential in Python script

Tags: python-3.x, hide, credentials, disassembly

What is the best method to hide credential in a Python script?
I would like to avoid storing it in clear text.

```
import paramiko

# how to avoid clear text ?
my_server='myserver'
my_password='mysecret'

ssh = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    ssh.connect(my_server, username='root', password=my_password)
except paramiko.SSHException:
    print("Connection Failed")
    quit()
```

If I create an myscript.exe with pyInstaller, is it possible to retrieve the clear text (my_server and my_password) "disassembling" the .exe?

Thanks

Comment: If you give your program out in any form, and your program uses a password, it is possible for someone to get the password.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if it's stored in clear text or not, if the script needs the password, everyone who has the script also has the password.

Store the credentials in a separate file (yaml comes to mind) and load that at runtime. Don't add the credentials file to the repository if every user uses their own credentials.

Comment: I will provide and exe built with pyInstaller, not the script .py

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. Your program itself has to use the clear text password, so even if the exe wasn't easily unpackable, people could read the password from memory. You simply cannot make someone else use a secret without them knowing the secret (unless you control their client).

Comment: Ok, got it thanks.
About "people could read the password from memory. " what do you mean?

Comment: Well, your user's computer is under the user's control. So whatever the program stores in RAM, the user can read with the right tools.